# Receipt Acknowledgment for publisher in VertX AMQP Bridge

Tags: vert.x, solace, vertx-verticle

How to receive acknowledgment for publisher in VertX AMQP Bridge to confirm on message receipt at solace VMR server.

Comment: I don't believe it's supported, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that this is possible using the Vert.x API.

There were some discussions on Vert.x's github, but I believe that it's never been resolved. https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/issues/1747